# Markup de etiquetas no funciona con acentos

Tags: bug, estado-completado, etiquetas

Puedes ver en [esta publicación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298/22) que el markup para las etiquetas con acentos no funciona:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @Konamiman creo que esto ya está estado-completado como en [spanish](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/a/2546/1674), ¿no? Le acabo de hacer un _rebake_ a la publicación que listada Flimzy y ya se ve bien.

Comment: Cierto, está solucionado, no sabía que se había mencionado en este sitio también. Gracias.